# Creating mongoose schema that contains array of Objects

Tags: express, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-models

How do I create a mongoose schema that has the following structure

```
 {
       data: {
        name: "John doe",
        attributes: [
          {
            text: "Sample text",
            created_at: "2018-08-23"
         },
        {
            text: "Sample text 2",
            created_at: "2018-08-23"
         }
        ],
       created_at: "2018-08-23"
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can simply be done with Arrays of Objects instead of creating New Schemas. I don't know if there might be some implications for the optimization.

```
    attributes: [{
    text: String,
    created_at: Date
}],
```

This is following the official Mongoose documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
const sampleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    data: {
        type: dataSchema
    }
});

const dataSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    attributes: [attributeSchema],
    created_at: Date
});

const attributeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    text: String,
    created_at: Date
});
```

Comment: Tried that but the created_at doesn't reflect

Comment: Change type as per your requirements. 
 You can use `Date.now()`

Comment: As per the Mongoose docs, mongoose has a timestamps property that automatically generates timestamps https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#timestamps.

My issue is that the timestamp gets applied to the main object but not to the array of objects.

Comment: I missed a property in `dataSchema` .  I have updated the snippet. Try the snippet now.